# Unable to to copy one Field to another filed Mongo db Native query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hi guys unable to copy one field value to another field in mongo db update many options, I am using mongo db 3.6, i attached my query below pls help me to overcome this issue.

```
db.am_task.updateMany(
                        {"reselleraccountid":{$exists:true}},
                        {$set:{"reselleraccountid":"$parantid"}}
                      )
```

Actual Results:

[image]

Expected Result

its should replace its value, not print its key name.

Comment: It is not possible in sinple update query, use update with aggregation pipeline starting from v4.2, just wrap update part in array bracket `[{$set:{"reselleraccountid":"$parantid"}}]`

Comment: okay thanks, I will check